# Performance Extension Method vs. Instance Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any performance difference between an instance method and an extension method?

Comment: Write the code both ways. Get out a stopwatch. Then you'll know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't forget extension methods are just static method calls wrapped in syntactic sugar.  So what you're really asking is

> Is there a performance difference between static and instance methods

The answer is yes and there are various articles available on this subject

Some links

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507639.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500596.aspx

Comment: I was hoping that you were going to add some citations to these articles as I've yet to find any. Perhaps I'm putting the wrong terms into google.

Comment: @Colin me too :).  I guess i didn't hit submit last time.  Try googling for "CLR method call performance"  Most articles take a general approach but will discuss the instance vs. static differences.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Links are just bringing to MSDN Magazine All Issues.

Answer (score 5):

I would doubt there would be any performance difference because it is all syntactic sugar. The compiler just compiles it just as any other method call, except it is to a static method on a different class.

Some more details from my blog about the syntactic sugar: http://colinmackay.co.uk/2007/06/18/method-extensions/

Comment: -1 In your blog, you're comparing a static method to a static method. That's different than an instance method...

Comment: That blog entry was written over two years ago, and its purpose was not to answer this exact question. My inclusion was mearly to demonstrate that Extension Methods are syntactic sugar by showing the underlying IL and how extension methods work in general. But, thank for down-voting!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make any significant difference. See [this article](http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2007/01/11/static-vs-instance-method-performance.aspx).

I've verified the results of the test, and did another test where the static variant had a parameter with type `Sample`. All of them took 11495ms (+/- 4ms) on my system for 2.1 billion calls. As the article says, you shouldn't be worrying about this.

Most examples and tests here aren't valid because they allow for method inlining. Especially easy on the compiler if the method is empty ;)

(interesting to see that the test was slower on my system than the one in the article.. it's not exactly slow, but it might be because of the 64bit OS)

Comment: I'm checking with the author if there is somewhere else where he put it online. In the meantime, you can read it on http://web.archive.org/web/20090624234442/http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2007/01/11/static-vs-instance-method-performance.aspx

Comment: Right, thanks, I did check his current blog too but it wasn't there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight performance difference, due to the number of arguments being passed into the method.  For instance, look at the following classes:

```
public class MyClassInstance
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClassInstance(int prop)
    {
        MyProperty = prop;
    }

    public void IncrementInstance()
    {
        MyProperty++;
    }
}

public static class MyClassStatic
{
    public static void IncrementStatic(this MyClassInstance i)
    {
        i.MyProperty++;
    }
}
```

running the following code:

```
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        MyClassInstance i = new MyClassInstance(0);

        for (int x = 0; x < 10000000; x++)
        {
            i.IncrementInstance();
        }

        TimeSpan td = d - DateTime.Now;

        DateTime e = DateTime.Now;

        for (int x = 0; x < 10000000; x++)
        {
            i.IncrementStatic();
        }

        TimeSpan te = e - DateTime.Now;
```

td = .2499 sec

te = .2655 sec

due to the fact that the instance method doesn't have to pass any arguments.

[heres](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) a slightly dated, but good article on performance

Comment: What happens to the "this" reference in an instance method call? Where does that go? How does that get passed? The method needs to get it from somewhere?

Comment: essentially both IncrementInstance and IncrementStatic call the Set Method for the MyProperty Property.  The instance method refers directly to the instance memory, while the static method refers to the instance passed in as an argument.

Comment: Curiously, I took your code and ran it on my machine. When I use the same number of iterations as you the numbers hop over one another. Sometimes instance methods win, sometimes the extension methods. I figure the timer isn't fine enough, so I set the iterations to over 2billion (int.MaxValue) and I'm now getting fairly consistent results. An iteration using the instance method takes 46 nanoseconds to complete, and an iteration using the extension method takes 45 nanoseconds to complete. I don't thing I'm going to be optimising anything one way or another based on a nanosecond of difference.

Comment: Your computer seems faster than mine  :)  he he   i should note that i ran it using the Visual Studio debugger and put a breakpoint just after te was assigned.  I agree though, extension methods' usefulness will almost always outweigh the performance hit you take.  It's not like Reflection where it's multitudes slower.  It's a very small difference.

Comment: @MarkSynowiec The point is, how does the instance method know where the “instance memory” is? The answer: it's passed as a hidden parameter. That means both methods actually have the same number of parameters, at least when performance is concerned.